How properly show up realtime message using pusher?
I'm having trouble with my websockets. I'm trying to use Pusher and Echo to display whether a user has logged in or logged out, but I can't figure out how to display the message. According to the browser logs, I'm connecting to the 'notifications' channel, but the UserSessionChanged event isn't triggered in my app.js for some reason. I'm new to websockets and this is my first time working with them, so it's possible I'm missing something obvious.
This is my event.
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;


class UserSessionChanged implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $type;


    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct($message, $type)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->type = $type;
        Log::debug('UserSessionChanged event initialized with message: ' . $this->message . ', type: ' . $this->type);


    }

     /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        Log::debug('Broadcasting on channel: notifications');

        return new Channel('notifications');
    }
}


this is one of 2 listeners for example
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use App\Events\UserSessionChanged;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class BroadcastUserLoginNotification
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(Login $event): void
    {
        Log::debug('Handling UserSessionChanged event: ' . $event->user->name . ' is online');

        broadcast(new UserSessionChanged("{$event->user->name} is online",'success'));
    }
}

this is app.js file
import './bootstrap';

console.log('Initializing Echo...');

const channel = window.Echo.channel('notifications');
console.log('Echo initialized for channel:', channel.name);
console.log('Channel state:', channel.state); // Stav kanálu (connected, disconnected, attemping)




window.Echo.channel('notifications').listen('UserSessionChanged', (e) => {
    console.log('Event received:', e);
    console.log('Message:', e.message);
    console.log('Type:', e.type);

    const notificationElement = document.getElementById('notification');
    notificationElement.innerText = e.message;

    notificationElement.classList.remove('invisible');
    notificationElement.classList.remove('alert-success');
    notificationElement.classList.remove('alert-danger');
    notificationElement.classList.add('alert-' + e.type);
});

this is bootstrap.js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;
console.log('Initializing Echo...');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ?? `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

/**

This is what I have in log when proceed login.
[2024-07-09 15:12:16] local.DEBUG: Handling UserSessionChanged event: test1 is online  
[2024-07-09 15:12:16] local.DEBUG: UserSessionChanged event initialized with message: test1 is online, type: success  

And this is in console in chrome like info,
Initializing Echo...
app.js:3 Initializing Echo...
app.js:6 Echo initialized for channel: notifications
app.js:7 Channel state: undefined

This is what I want to show to user
 <main class="py-4">
            <div id="notification" class="alert mx-3 invisible"></div>
            @yield('content')
        </main>

Edit: Is it necessary run php artisan queue:work or listen??
